# My Bot is not sending any messages after i execute the command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I've been trying to execute a test command, but the bot is not responding. It's online and it doesn't gives any errors. Code I've Tried:

Cog command:

```py
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def test(self, ctx):
            await ctx.send("Hey")
```

Main File:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='b!', case_insensitive = True, intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Heyo!')
    print('--------')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Bounce Café"))


for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")



bot.run('Token')
```

Comment: I assume you're on 1.7.3 because cog loading is not async yet. Try `intents.message_content = True`.

Comment: I'm going to try that, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: The bot now says that the command it's not found, maybe the cog loading it's not working. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: That could be possible. What does [`print(bot.commands)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.commands) say?

Comment: Nevermind, just fixed it, but thanks.